# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have an insert statement before these updates:
On db.sumbitchanges the error is shown.

```
Topic top = (from t in db.Topics
                 where t.id == id
                 select t).SingleOrDefault();

top.lastpost = username + maxdate;


Category ca = (from c in db.Categories
             where c.categoryid == cat
             select c).SingleOrDefault();

ca.totaltopics = ca.totaltopics + 1;
ca.posts = ca.posts + 1;
ca.lastpost = username + maxdate;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like either `top.lastpost` or `ca.lastpost` (or both) doesn't have enough space on the db to hold `username` + `maxdate`.

Check how many characters the database fields allow and either change the field to allow more characters or reduce the length of the output - perhaps only storing `username + maxdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` or `username + maxdate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume both `Topic.lastpost` and `Category.lastpost` are `string`s, and `username + maxdate` concatenates two strings. The result might be a bit bigger than what would fit into `lastpost` column in respective table.

Answer (score 0):

The string is longer than the size of the DB column so the resulting data doesn't fit inside.